# Como paso una variable de.js externo a un script dentro de otro HTML

Tags: html, json, javascript-objeto

estoy en un proyecto de Universidad y tengo un objeto extraído de JSON utilizando la función .fetch y queda algo así

```
{id: "id_objeto", nombre: "nombre_objeto", desc: "desc_objeto"}
```

Estuve buscando soluciones aquí en Stackoverflow y ví una de crear variables globales y llamarlas desde el script. Lo hice pero me dice q no está definido.

Básicamente quiero pasar el objeto obtenido q guardé en una variable global para el script embebido en mi HTML. Obtengo el codigo pero me dice *undefine* cuando hago *console.log(objeto)*.

Codigo del main.js

```
 //variable global
 var datos = '';

 function datos(valor) {
 fetch('_data/soft.json')
 .then(resultado => resultado.json()) 
 .then(data => {
 const val = data[valor]
 datos = val;
 }) 
 }
```

Codigo del HTML

```
console.log(datos)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahora en JavaScript podemos usar los módulos para exportar recursos a otros archivos js. Por ejemplo, si usted tiene en un archivo una variable para poder utilizar esta en otro archivo debe volverla exportable con la palabra `export`, es igual para exportar las funciones.

En el archivo auxiliar.js:

```
export let datos = "algun dato";
export function saludar(){
  console.log("HOLA MUNDO");
}
```

Usted puede importar éstos en otro archivo con las palabras reservadas `import` y `from`

En el archivo main.js:

```
import { datos, saludar } from "./auxiliar.js";
console.log(datos);
saludar();
```

Importante, a la hora de llamar el archivo en el documento HTML debe especificar `type="module"`

```
<script src=".js/main.js" type="module"></script>
```

También se puede exportar por `default` y más cosas, para eso puede ir a [Módulos JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)